# What DC motor is fit to replace this AC one?

Tags: arduino, motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I've a machine with this motor:

[image]

I would like to swap this one with a DC motor in order to have better control, maybe a stepper one so that it could be controlled via an arduino board and a dedicated dc motor driver like this one: https://a.co/d/feRMU1B

What physical specifications should I look for in a DC motor if I want to be able to have similar performances? thanks!

Comment: you asked this before ... today's shopping question is off topic here

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* user3450548, but I'm afraid that *[shopping questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)* really aren't a good fit for a stack exchange site. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*. Take a look at [ask] and [about] for more information on how stack exchange works, and the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) for details of how to write a good question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question.

Comment: @Ben tried to change the question in order to better fit the robotics se rules 

Comment: The physical specifications you need are power/speed/torque; any two will dictate the third. You should also consider physical size when you look at replacements; the picture you have looks cramped and I think you're unlikely to find a DC motor with comparable torque/power output that would fit in the same space as the AC motor you've shown.

Comment: @Chuck ok so if the power is around 14W, assuming 230v ac and 30 revolutions per minute I should have a torque of 4.16 Nm. I can pick any 12v stepper motor that meets a minimum of 30 rpm and a torque around 4 Nm ?

Comment: I mean, you can try. At 12 volts, you'd need about 1.2 amps to get to 14 watts. Digikey isn't the catalog of everything (and I'm not affiliated) but the highest current rating I see for 12 V stepper motors is 0.55 amps. Highest holding torque I see for 12 V stepper motors is 0.23 Nm. Lowest (reasonble) voltage I see for a 4 Nm stepper motor is 24 V, it draws almost 2 amps, and it's $185. Product description for your amazon link calls it a fungal nail treatment; just be careful you know what you're getting!

Comment: @Chuck what? nail treatment? XD to me it brings to "BTS7960 43A Module Motor Driver Controller Board Module Stepper Motor DC Dual H-Bridge for Smart Car Power, Industrial Supplies". Anyways my original problem was that the speed of the device was too fast so getting a lower power motor with also low rpm is suggested? I found some DC motor I guess geared down. Example is a 12V DC 8-1000 RPM that with a reduction ratio of 810 goes around 8rpm and a torque of 35kg/cm that should be around 3.43 Nm

Comment: Read down to the description and features! :P For your geared down DC motor you're at 3.43 Nm vs 4.16 Nm, which is about 18% too low, and the speed is 8 rpm vs 30 rpm, so 73% too low there. You're probably going to really struggle finding a suitable 12 VDC replacement for that motor.

Comment: @Chuck isn't what I want having a slower motor ? Maybe I'm missing something. My goal was having a motor being able to move more slower maybe in a range between 5 and 30 rpm. Do you mean that in general is way too weak? I'm starting to understand, right because if I switch the motor to increase the rpm the torque drops even more... right?

Comment: You said you were looking to swap the motor for better control. I assumed you meant you thought that it would be easier to position a stepper motor than it would be to position an AC motor. If you want the same functionality, then you need to match torque/speed specifications (and it needs to fit! lol). If you just mean that you want it to go slower, then you might be better off replacing the power electronics that drive the existing motor (like a VFD) than in replacing the motor with something else.

Comment: @Chuck right, well if it could have been possible to easily replace it with a dc stepper one, the better. However I'm searching online and it seems that a geared one with low rpm and a comparable torque is hard to find unless you pay a lot. :( I'm new to motors, I tought it was more easy find any kind of motors given you know the specifications...

Comment: Motors aren't awful to find, generally speaking, but I think it's going to be nearly impossible to get the same power rating as a 220/240VAC motor in a 12VDC style :(

Comment: @Chuck I see, if I go up to 24V could be easier? I see that lot of arduino shields / drivers allow up to 36VDC for the connected load so a 24VDC motor could work too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139682/discussion-between-chuck-and-user3450548).